# Strange behavior of skimage.morphology.skeletonize3d

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

It is strange the if using `skimage.morphology.skeletonize_3d`on structure as below. It will remove all elements. Such structure is a equilateral triangle in 3d space.

```
array = np.array([
    [[0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0]],
    
    [[0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0]],
    
    [[0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0]]]).astype('uint8')
morphology.skeletonize_3d(array)
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

It results as an empty array. This is strange. Could anyone explain it? How to avoid it?

Comment: Have you checked, if [that](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3757) might be the same issue?

Comment: @HansHirse I'm not sure. But it seems a same one. So it is still a bug..